# On animation end the thumbnail view (view being animated) is shifted up and left of its original position. How to avoid this?

Tags: android, zooming, android-animation

I am following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) training article of developer.android.com to zoom a view in Android. In this article there are two ImageViews used one is ImageView which is a thumbnail (to be zoomed) & other is also ImageView which is a zoomed view which covers the whole screen. The application behaviour is as expected when using ImageViews for thumbnail & zoomed view. But when I use [GestureImageView](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview) in place of second ImageView which is zoomed ImageView the thumbnail shifts to left when GestureImageView (zoomed view) is clicked to hide zoomed view after complete cycle of clicking to show zoomed view & clicking to hide zoomed view, as shown below:

[image: Shifted thumbnail after zoomed view clicked to hide itself]

Following is the code that I am using:

```
private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, Drawable imageResBitmap) {
    // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
    // immediately and proceed with this one.
    if (currentAnimator != null) {
        currentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
    expandedImageView.setImageDrawable(imageResBitmap);

    // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
    // This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
    // and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container
    // view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
    // bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
    // properties (X, Y).
    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    //Log.i("-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y", -globalOffset.x + "" + -globalOffset.y);

    // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
    // bounds using the "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable
    // stretching during the animation. Also calculate the start scaling
    // factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).
    float startScale;
    //Log.i("(float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()", (float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() + "");
    //Log.i("(float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()", (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height() + "");
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
            > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
        // Extend start bounds horizontally
        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        //Log.i("startScale", startScale + "");
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        //Log.i("startWidth", startWidth + "");
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        //Log.i("deltaWidth", deltaWidth + "");
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {
        // Extend start bounds vertically
        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        //Log.i("startScale", startScale + "");
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        //Log.i("startHeight", startHeight + "");
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        //Log.i("deltaHeight", deltaHeight + "");
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }

    // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
    // begins, it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the
    // thumbnail.
    thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations
    // to the top-left corner of the zoomed-in view (the default
    // is the center of the view).
    expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
    expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

    // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
    // scale properties (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set
            .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                    startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                    startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
            startScale, 1f)).with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                    View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            currentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            currentAnimator = null;
        }
    });
    set.start();
    currentAnimator = set;

    // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down
    // to the original bounds and show the thumbnail instead of
    // the expanded image.
    final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (currentAnimator != null) {
                currentAnimator.cancel();
            }

            // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
            // back to their original values.
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            //Log.i("startBounds.left, startBounds.top", startBounds.left + ", " + startBounds.top);
            set.play(ObjectAnimator
                        .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                        View.Y,startBounds.top))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                        View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                        View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
            set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
            set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    currentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    currentAnimator = null;
                }
            });
            set.start();
            currentAnimator = set;
        }
    });
}
```

In my xml:

```
<com.polites.android.GestureImageView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
    gesture-image:min-scale="0.1"
    gesture-image:strict="false" />
```

I experimented with the above java code but it did not work as expected, i.e. thumbnail still shifts to left when zoomed view is clicked to hide itself.

I want the thumbnail to stay in its original place when GestureImageView (zoomed view) is clicked to hide itself. **On animation end the thumbnail is shifted up and left. How to avoid this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using GestureImageView for thumbnail view also, so I am using 2 GestureImageViews one for thumbnail & other for zoomed view. Which prevents thumbnail view from getting shifting when zoomed view is clicked to hide itself.